# SQL Server 2012 - cannot login

Tags: sql-server-2012, windows-server

Just installed a single instance of SQL Server 2012. The instance name is called Example and the server is called WIN2K8R2. It's on a virtual machine and I am RDP'd into it. I'm trying to login with SQL Server Management Studio.

When trying to login, I get this error.

A network-related or instance-specific error occured while establishing a connection to the SQL server.

All SQL Server Services are 'running'. It's a clean build of Win2k8 R2.

Server Type: Database Engine
Server Name: WIN2k8R2\Example
Auth: Windows Auth

---

Resolved.

1) Deleted VM.
2) Spun up a new VM.
3) Installed SQL Server 2012

Able to login to the database from RDP.

Comment: Which edition of SQL Server, Dev, Standard, Express?  Also, are you trying to connect remotely or locally?

Comment: It's an Eval copy currently. I am connecting to the server via RDP and opening SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Since you are local to the server it should be connecting via Shared Memory. Are you sure the server name is correct and that you are working with a named instance? Are you sure you RDP'd into the correct server (command prompt and type: hostname)?

Comment: Here is a link that might help: http://www.sswug.org/articlesection/default.aspx?TargetID=44331  Also it would be helpful if you could put the full error.  Usually there is more after that.

Comment: Are you 100% positive the instance is running and the instance name is called `Example`? This is not a permissions error - it isn't even getting that far. Sounds like something else is either not right or not as you think.

Comment: Shawn: Yes, I'm connected to the correct server and instance.

Answer (score 2):

During installation you were prompted to add Windows users to the SQL instance. Did you add any? Unless you added yourself as a SQL user you won't be able to connect.

- if you added Administrators as SQL users then you must run SSMS w/o the LUA token restriction, in other words you must right click the launch icon and select "run as Administrator"
- if you did not add any user as  SQL user then you must follow the steps described in [Connect to SQL Server When System Administrators Are Locked Out](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx)
- if you don't know what you did and cannot follow the steps mentioned above, discard the VM and install SQL again. Pay attention to the installation procedure and make sure you add yourself as a valid SQL user. Read [Database Engine Configuration - Account Provisioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281849%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) for more details.

> All SQL Server Services are 'running'.

Make sure [SQL Server Browser Service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087.aspx) is running.

Comment: Ended up rebuilding a new VM. Will post an update once the installation finishes.

Answer (score 1):

When setting up SQL Server, by default TCP/IP connections are disabled.  This will prevent you from connecting remotely to your instance.  You will need to enable this.

1. Open your [SQL Server Configuration Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174212.aspx).
2. Browse to "SQL Server Network Configuration" (make sure it's for your appropriate architecture, 32bit or 64bit).
3. Under that, browse to the protocols for your instance (probably MSSQLSERVER unless you have a named instance).
4. It will likely say "Disabled". If so, right click and enable.
5. Restart your SQL Server instance.

More detailed instructions can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909712.aspx).

Comment: It was enabled by default.